# how to use ifTHEN statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I'm new to R and trying to do simple if/then statements.  Using dataframe `DFnew`, I want to execute:

```
if "location2" is not missing then "Location" = "location2"
```

My code:

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% DFnew %>%
  if(location2 != NA){
    Location <- location2
  }
```

Comment: Please include the necessary `library()` statements to make this code reproducible; your code implies you're using `dplyr`, because otherwise references to dataframe columns as 'location2' , `Location` would require you to write `DFnew['location']`

Comment: Then, you need to explain whether 'location2', 'Location' are simple variables or column names in your DF. Presumably the latter. In which case you want to vectorize the if-then expression and assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the vectorized function `ifelse` or `if_else` if you are using `dplyr`. To check for `NA` values use the function `is.na`.

```
library(dplyr)

DFnew %>% mutate(Location = if_else(!is.na(location2), location2, Location))
```

The same can be achieved with `coalesce` as :

```
DFnew %>% mutate(Location = coalesce(location2, Location))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
DFnew %>%
      mutate(Location = case_when(!is.na(location2) ~ location2, TRUE ~ location))
```